# Checking whether at least n/2 + 1 elements of a set/vector are equal

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

We have a set of elements, say a vector of $n$ elements (actually, the data structure really doesn't matter in this case). It is NOT sorted. We want to check whether at least $n/2 + 1$ elements are equal.

I have been thinking about an efficient algorithm to do so but I don't know, the fact that it is not sorted makes it quite difficult for me.

If it was sorted, we could do it with an $O(n)$ algorithm, I'd say: just iterate over the vector, saving the most common element. If the counter arrives to $n/2 + 1$, we are done.

Could you give me some advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a standard exercise -- I suggest you think about it some more, especially in the context of the course in which it was set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me a hint, at least? What about Hoare's selection to find the median (O(log(n)), and then checking how many times does this element appear? This would be O(log(n) + n), but I'm being asked to find a O(nlog(n)).

Comment: An algorithm which runs in time $O(\log n + n)$ also runs in time $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: @Jose If all you want is an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm, just sort the list. Hoare's selection algorithm requires at least linear time (you can't possibly find the $k$th-largest element of a list without looking at every element) and may take quadratic time in the worst case.

Comment: (Not knowing what David Richerby is thinking of,) First hint: $O(n)$ does not mean/imply *single pass*. (Errm - $O(nlogn)$? Well, sure includes $O(n)$.)

Comment: @Jose is this the answer you've been looking for? Please mark it accordingly if so  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an even better approach to your problem:

1. The element you are looking for will also be the median of the list. Find the median of the list using the [Median of Medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm. **$O(n)$ complexity**
2. Check if the median appears at least $n/2 + 1$ times on the list **$O(n)$ complexity**

So, the algorithm you're looking for runs in linear time.

Comment: I'm not sure the condition $count=n/2+1$ is correct. If the array consists of $n/2+1$ copies of $x$ followed by $n/2-1$ copies of $y$, you will get 2 at the end.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus   Thanks, I misinterpreted the problem. Now I updated the solution, feel free to check it :)